# How to access a variable from a H file

Tags: ios, objective-c, constants

I'm defining some variables in a Constants.h file.

```
#ifndef Constants_h
#define Constants_h

static NSString *SERVER_IMG_URL = @"http://localhost/img";
...
```

If I import Constants.h in a M file. How I can access to SERVER_IMG_URL??

I want to use it, to not repeat the url in all files, only call this variable. Because, If I need to change the IP, changes it in one file, not more.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i hope this helps..

write this in constant file..

```
#define kURLname   @"http://localhost/img"
```

after importing constant file in .m use it like this in ur projects .m file...

```
NSString *SERVER_IMG_URL = kURLname;
```

Answer (score 2):

In Constant.h file you can declare a variable as

`FOUNDATION_EXPORT NSString *const SERVER_IMG_URL;`

and in the .m file

```
NSString *const SERVER_IMG_URL = @"http://localhost/img";
```

after that import Contant.h in .pch file so that whole project will get access to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

I would avoid using #define if you can.

They are harder to debug since they get unpacked at preprocess time (so the  code you wrote and what you actually run may not be *quite* the same) and lack potential type safety checks you could get from a named type.

I would use a VMConstants.h and VMConstants.m pair to solve this.

Start with something like this in your VMConstants.h

```
extern const NSString * const kURLname;
```

then in your VMConstants.m file

```
const NSString * const kURLname = @"http://localhost/img";
```

I would use as much const as you can get away with, so that it's as immutable as possible (less moving parts) and add a suitable prefix to your Constants name to avoid clashes with anyone else who thinks their third party library needs a Constants too.

I would also ask yourself if you *really* need that Constants file because, in all likelihood, it will become a dumping ground for stuff over time and just grow and grow until your app is utterly entwined with it.

Worse, people may re-use values there in ways they were not intended. Colors are a common one for this happening, I find and suddenly your buttons and nav bar UI are interlinked.

In short, avoid exposing the literal values where you can (so, put them in the m and just expose the type name in the h), and avoid globals at all where possible.